# Dropping a single (sub-) column from a MultiIndex

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, multi-index

I have the following dataframe `df`

```
    col1        col2        col3
    a     b     a     b     a     b       
1   ...
2
3
```

and just cannot figure out how to drop only a single 'sublevel', e.g. `df.col1.a`

I can `df.col1.drop('a', axis=1)`, but reassigning it like `df.col1=df.col1.drop('a', axis=1)` fails.

The logical structure `df.colums` I understand, but how should I be modifying it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Drop](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) is a very flexible method, and there are quite a few ways to use it:

```
In [11]: mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], ['a', 'b']])

In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame(1, index=[0], columns=mi)

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
   col1     col2     col3
      a  b     a  b     a  b
0     1  1     1  1     1  1
```

Drop a single column using a tuple:

```
In [14]: df.drop(('col1', 'a'), axis=1)
Out[14]:
   col1  col2     col3
      b     a  b     a  b
0     1     1  1     1  1
```

or a list using a list of tuples:

```
In [15]: df.drop([('col1', 'a'), ('col2', 'b')], axis=1)
Out[15]:
   col1  col2  col3
      b     a     a  b
0     1     1     1  1
```

or across a level, e.g. all `a`s:

```
In [16]: df.drop('a', level=1, axis=1)
Out[16]:
   col1  col2  col3
      b     b     b
0     1     1     1
```

*In 0.14, you'll also be able to pass regex of what to drop...*

There's also a way to drop the entire level of a index/column:

```
In [21]: df.columns.droplevel(1)
Out[21]: Index([u'col1', u'col1', u'col2', u'col2', u'col3', u'col3'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you! I was unable to find this in the pandas documentation.

Comment: I'm actually in the [process of rewriting these functions](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6599), so will check that all the ways to use are covered in the docs :) (I didn't know all the ins an outs until recently!)

Comment: @AndyHayden can u answer to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57709834/how-to-remove-specific-columns-from-multi-index-based-on-date-condition/57714678#57714678