# Drop a level from a single column in pandas multi index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

I have the following dataframe df

```
    col1        col2        col3
    a     b     a     b     a     b       
1   x1    x1   y11    y12   z11   z12  
2   x2    x2   y21    y22   z21   z22
3   x3    x3   y31    y32   z31   z32
```

Suppose 'a' and 'b' are identical for col1. I want to drop the entire level 'letters' ('a', 'b'), but only from col1. I do not want to use drop() to drop either 'a' or 'b', as in [Dropping a single (sub-) column from a MultiIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397058/dropping-a-single-sub-column-from-a-multiindex).

I want instead to remove the level from col1, to obtain

```
    col1        col2        col3
                a     b     a     b       
1   x1         y11    y12   z11   z12  
2   x2         y21    y22   z21   z22
3   x3         y31    y32   z31   z32
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. It is a pretty hack-heavy work around, but I don't believe pandas naturally supports this sort of functionality with multi-indexing. I broke down all of the steps to show more specifically how I got to the result, but you could easily simplify this some more.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    arrays = [np.array(['col1', 'col1', 'col2', 'col2', 'col3', 'col3']),
              np.array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'])]
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 6), columns=arrays)

    df_part = df[df.columns[:2]]
    df_part2 = df[df.columns[2:]]

    df_part.columns.set_levels(['a', ''], level=1, inplace=True)
    new_df = pd.concat([df_part, df_part2], axis=1)
    result = new_df[new_df.columns[1:]]
```