# How to remove specific columns from multi-index based on date condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I need to drop the subcolumns from multiindex dataframe based on today's date

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['PC', 'Geo', 'Comp'], values=['Bill1', 'Bill2', Bill3], 
                        columns=['Month'], fill_value=0)
```

**dataframe before pivot table**

[image]

**desired output**

**please note that the output is based on current month**

**if today's date >15**

[image: today's date >15]

**if today's date <15**
    [image: todays date<15]

Comment: Can you explain your logic in a bit more detail?

Comment: @Tom...i have created a pivot table from a dataframe....please ignore the code above pivot table formula..</br> **bill1 , bill2, bill3** has values based on date... </br>
i need the **bill1** to have value only for one month **(which is based on the current date)**</br>  **theres no change in the bill2 & bill3

Comment: Can you create data sample before `pivot_table` ?

Comment: @PraveenSnowy Could you provide a complete example of what you want your output `df` to look like?

Comment: Yes, but what are values `ROM` ? It is problem, because there are mixed values datetimes with strings, so are there necessary?

Comment: @Tom... please have a look at my question now.. i have modified it as better as i can

Comment: @jezrael... i need to drop the sub-column  (months) for **Bill1 column**.. is that possible?
its like  **`df= df.drop(('Bill1', '2019-01-01 00:00:00'), axis=1)`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your code as below.

```
df.iloc[:,np.in1d(df.columns.get_level_values(1), [dat])]
```

Hope this will solve your problem.